# How to change V-select text colour for label and items?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've been trying to change v-select text colour for the label and items but can't find the prop to do that, I can change the background-color but not the label or text items inside the v-select. Sample code below

```
<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-container fluid>
            <v-row align="center">
                <v-col
                 class="d-flex"
                 cols="12"
                 sm="6"
                 >
                 <v-select
                 :items="items"
                 label="Standard"
                 background-color="#000000"
                 color="#ffffff"
          ></v-select>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `item` slot to customize the label rendering :

```
<v-select :items="items" label="Standard" background-color="#000000" color="#ffffff">
  <template #item="{item}">
    <span style="color:white; background:blue">{{item.name}}<span>
  </template>
</v-select>
```